# ItemControl Binding inside another ItemControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to bind a ObservableCollection inside another ObservableCollection. The xaml is as below. The outer ItemControl works fine and the 'RangeLeft' property is displayed fine. The problem is with the Inner ItemControl. The count of Wrap Panels(in the inner ItemControl) are created is according to the items in the inner list but the property 'ContionalString' is never displayed.

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding mMngModelList}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <Expander>
    <StackPanel >
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RangeLeft}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConditionString}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="     "/>
                        <Button Content="+" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
   </Expander>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code Behind is

```
public class ManagementFunctionModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    #region members
    string _Type;
    int _RangeLeft;
    int _RangeTop;
    int _RangeRight;
    int _RangeBottom;
    public ObservableCollection<Condition> _ConditionList { get; private set;      }
#endregion

public ManagementFunctionModel()
{
    _ConditionList = new ObservableCollection<Condition>();
    _ConditionList.Add(new Condition() { ConditionString = "condition 1" });
    _ConditionList.Add(new Condition() { ConditionString = "condition 2" });
    _ConditionList.Add(new Condition() { ConditionString = "condition 3" });
}


public ObservableCollection<Condition> ConditionList
{
    get { return _ConditionList; }
    set
    {
        if (_ConditionList != value)
        {
            _ConditionList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ConditionList");
        }
    }
}

public int RangeLeft
{
    get { return _RangeLeft; }
    set
    {
        if (_RangeLeft != value)
        {
            _RangeLeft = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("RangeLeft");
        }
    }
}
```

Condition Class

```
public class Condition
{
    public string ConditionString;
}
```

In my view

```
    mMngModelList = new ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel>();

    mMngModelListShow.Add(new ManagementFunctionModel() { RangeLeft = 9, RangeTop = 3 });
    mMngModelListShow.Add(new ManagementFunctionModel() { RangeLeft = 10, RangeTop = 1 });
    mMngModelListShow.Add(new ManagementFunctionModel() { RangeLeft = 11, RangeTop = 2 });
```

Comment: `{Binding DataContext.ConditionString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}` - Or use ancestorlevel, or elementname="itemscontrolname" etc.

Comment: I assume you mean this should be binding for text control? What should be the ItemSource for inner item control? Actually its not working for me

Comment: @user2837961 `ConditionString` is a field. Make it a property (add `{ get; set; }`). You cannot bind to fields.

Comment: @dkozl I did that but still does not work

Comment: install the free tool WPF inspector. It will simplify the debugging of the bindings. It looks weired. I've done this 1000 times and it should work without any problems. Check the spelling in XAML.

Comment: Yea sorry I tend to speed through these things in between distractions at work, looks like you got your remedy though. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and if if you declare the **ConditionString** in the **Condition** class as a property instead of a classic field it works fine. This is my test code :

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mMngModelList = new ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel>();

        mMngModelList.Add(new ManagementFunctionModel() { RangeLeft = 9 });
        mMngModelList.Add(new ManagementFunctionModel() { RangeLeft = 10 });
        mMngModelList.Add(new ManagementFunctionModel() { RangeLeft = 11 });

        this.DataContext = mMngModelList;
    }
}

public class Condition
{
    public string ConditionString { get; set; }
}

public class ManagementFunctionModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    #region members
    string _Type;
    int _RangeLeft;
    int _RangeTop;
    int _RangeRight;
    int _RangeBottom;
    public ObservableCollection<Condition> _ConditionList { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    public ManagementFunctionModel()
    {
        _ConditionList = new ObservableCollection<Condition>();
        _ConditionList.Add(new Condition() { ConditionString = "condition 1" });
        _ConditionList.Add(new Condition() { ConditionString = "condition 2" });
        _ConditionList.Add(new Condition() { ConditionString = "condition 3" });
    }


    public ObservableCollection<Condition> ConditionList
    {
        get { return _ConditionList; }
        set
        {
            if (_ConditionList != value)
            {
                _ConditionList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ConditionList");
            }
        }
    }

    public int RangeLeft
    {
        get { return _RangeLeft; }
        set
        {
            if (_RangeLeft != value)
            {
                _RangeLeft = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("RangeLeft");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(String property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

And this is the UI code :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RangeLeft}"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionList}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConditionString}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="        "/>
                                        <Button Content="+" />
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works for me as well. Actually I had changed the Binding as Chris suggested.